# Type inference for java8 streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying out the java8 streams for the first time and having a bit of a wrinkle with the syntax wrt type inference. Here is the snippet:

The core of it is:

```
Arrays.stream(stringArray).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

This results in:

```
Error:(56, 84) java: method collect in interface java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>
  found: java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.util.List<java.lang.Object>>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Here is a more complete snippet:

```
try {
    br =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  list.add(Arrays.stream(line.split(","))
  .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

I have tried a few similar approaches/tweaks but have not yet broken through. Tips appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't about type inference at all, but rather that `IntStream` does not have an overloaded `collect` method that accepts a `Collector`.  Instead, you can call `IntStream#boxed` to map it into a `Stream<Integer>`, and then collect it to a `List<Integer>`:

```
Arrays.stream(stringArray)
      .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
      .boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

An even simpler solution would be to map it to a `Stream<Integer>` directly:

```
Arrays.stream(stringArray)
      .map(Integer::parseInt)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Or just use `map()` instead of `mapToInt()`.

Comment: @javadba Are you sure it's the same error? Is `list` a `List<List<Integer>>`?

Comment: `List<Integer[]> list  = null;`

Comment: @javadba This returns a `List<Integer>`, as stated in the first paragraph.

Comment: @javadba Well of course a `List<Integer>` is not a `Integer[]`. Try `.toArray(Integer[]::new)` instead.

Comment: Ah ok so i changed to `        List<List<Integer>> list  = null` and that works.

Comment: i had had the `.toArray()` before it was not working. don't remember why. oh i see the `Collectors` does not have `toArray`: so where is the `.toArray` you mention?

Comment: @javadba It's a `Stream` method.